# Hide/Show Mapbox points/clusters based on client side filtering?

Tags: filter, mapbox

I have a webpage that offers clients to perform filter operations.
[See image of my interface here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkmLJ.jpg). The user can filter results based on the countries in the squares.

Everything is working fine, my view updates perfectly when user filters.

However, I cannot find a solution to **update the map** on filter, like I am updating the content.

I am wondering how to ask Mapbox to listen for click event outside of the map, or to stay updated with what is filered on the interface.
It's the same example than [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/), except that instead of having to click on the menu inside the map to filter the results on the map, I want the results on the map to be automatically filtered based on my other filter (the one with square regions of the world, shown on my interface
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkmLJ.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` variable to trigger map changes from outside the map:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoiam93ZXQiLCJhIjoiY2wzcTlhOTc0MTJ5aDNwbDJlNG5ncDAzZiJ9.PiDzh6BzO92pueGLxv1w5g'; 

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', 
  center: [-87.661557, 41.893748],
  zoom: 10.7
});

var flyToButton = document.getElementById('flyToButton');
flyToButton.addEventListener('click', handleZoomButtonClick);

function handleZoomButtonClick() {
  map.flyTo({
    center: [-74.5, 40],
    essential: true 
  });
}

var addLayerButton = document.getElementById('addLayerButton');
addLayerButton.addEventListener('click', handleAddLayerButton);

function handleAddLayerButton() {
  map.addSource('urban-areas', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/ne_50m_urban_areas.geojson'
    });
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'urban-areas-fill',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'urban-areas',
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': '#f08',
      'fill-opacity': 0.4
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}
#map { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
}
#flyToButton {
  position: absolute; 
}
#addLayerButton {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 30px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Points on a map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.8.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.8.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <button id="flyToButton">Fly to</button>
    <button id="addLayerButton">Add layer</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

How you can implement the filter functionality depends on the type of your data. But probably the following mapbox example will help you: [Filter features within map view](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/)